# D3: Get html element associated with node?

Tags: d3.js, svg

I'm working on a map ([found here](http://www.taylorchasewhite.com/d3/states/)), that is using the svg viewbox attribute to scale with the size of the client.

Unfortunately the project I'm using, d3.geoAlbersUsa() does not seem to scale the tooltip correctly with the rest of the SVG. As in, it suddenly places the tooltip in the same spot it would be if the client width had been the original 960x500 specs.

Here's the tooltip code:

```
d3.tsv("CitiesTraveledTo.tsv",cityVisited, function(data) {
    var cities = svg.selectAll(".city")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .classed("city",true);
        
        cities.append("line")
        .attr("x1", function(d) {
            return projection([d.Longitude, d.Latitude])[0];
        })
        .attr("x2", function(d) {
            return projection([d.Longitude, d.Latitude])[0];
        })
        .attr("y1", function(d) {
            return projection([d.Longitude, d.Latitude])[1]-pinLength;
        })
        .attr("y2", function(d) {
            return (projection([d.Longitude, d.Latitude])[1]);
        })
        .attr("stroke-width",function(d) {
            return 2;
        })
        .attr("stroke",function(d) {
            return "grey";
        });
        
        cities.append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
            return projection([d.Longitude, d.Latitude])[0];
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
            return projection([d.Longitude, d.Latitude])[1]-pinLength;
        })
        .attr("r", function(d) {
            return 3;
        })
        .style("fill", function(d) {
            if (d.Reason === "Work") {
                return "rgb(214, 69, 65)";
            }
            else if (d.Reason === "Fun") {
                return "rgb(245, 215, 110)";
            }
            else {
                return "rgb(214, 69, 65)";
            }
        })  
        .style("opacity", 1.0)  

        // Modification of custom tooltip code provided by Malcolm Maclean, "D3 Tips and Tricks" 
        // http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/adding-tooltips-to-d3js-graph.html
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {
            div.transition()
                .duration(200)
                .style("opacity", .9);
            div.text(d.City + ", " + d.State)
                .style("left", function() {
                    var centerCircle = (projection([d.Longitude, d.Latitude])[0]);
                    return  (centerCircle-26) + "px";
                })     
                .style("top", function() {
                    var centerCircle = projection([d.Longitude, d.Latitude])[1];
                    var circleRadius = 3;
                    
                    return ( centerCircle - circleRadius - 33-pinLength) + "px";
                });
            div.append("div").attr("class","arrow-down");
        })   

        // fade out tooltip on mouse out               
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
            div.transition()        
               .duration(500)      
               .style("opacity", 0);   
        });
```

I thought that the scaling should just happen automatically for the tooltip as well. Wrong. I then tried to reset the height and width passed to the projection and that didn't work. What's the best way to get the element bound to a data "d" node?

I ask because it will likely be easier to say "for this node, get me this element, give me the bound html element", so that I can set the position of the tooltip relative to the new position of the bound element.

Comment: Since the `div` is defined outside the SVG it won't be subject to the transformations you're applying to the map. Consider making a tooltip within the SVG instead so you don't need to apply the transformation again, or consider reading the mouse position from the event.

Comment: Have you tried using `this` or `d3.select(this).node()`?